# pdfmake use in an application with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, pdfmake

I'm just going to build an application in Webpack and would like to integrate pdfmake unfortunately I encounter this problems.
I have the file "pdfmake.js" are in my "web_modules" folder and put them with

```
Var pdfmake = require(" pdfmake ");
```

When I call the:

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open ();
```

doing, he tells me "CreatePDF" is not a function that has struck me, and I found that I call the "File Saver" and not "pdfmake" get back at these locations.
Has this happened to anyone of you have an idea?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: i solved my problem with the following code line:
**require("script!pdfmake");**
You have to use the scriptloader from webpack.

Comment: pdfmake is exposing different apis depending on the environment (which is not good imho). I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/150) for that.

Comment: @circy Can you move that comment as an answer and mark it as a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem with the following code line: require("script!pdfmake"); You have to use the scriptloader from webpack.

Comment: can you please show me your config, i can't for the life of me use this library with webpack

Comment: If you webpack and pdfmake lib from the build folder [link](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/tree/master/build)  used it would have to go is white following. 

require("script!**./Path to the lib pdfmake***");
Then you can run without what to initialize the following command immediately:
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition)

Comment: If you NPM USER it's even easier.
NPM install pdfmake

npm install pdfmake
var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
var fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: 'citycontrasts.ttf'
    }
};

var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

So it should also run without Problehme in Webpack.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I've replied here as well since I can get neither of your examples to work and I'm kinda stuck at the moment: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/150

Comment: I get "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'script'" when I use this require

Comment: did you install the webpack script loader?