# PDFmake: pdfmake.createPdf is not a function

Tags: webpack, pdfmake

After installing `pdfmake` using npm:

```
npm install pdfmake --save-dev
```

and compiling bundles with `webpack` I get an error when running:

```
pdfmake = require 'pdfmake'
pdfmake.createPdf(doc_definition).download('test.pdf')
```

Saying:

```
pdfmake.createPdf is not a function
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421528/pdfmake-use-in-an-application-with-webpack) suggestion, installed the script-loader and changed the requirement to:

```
pdfmake = require 'script!pdfmake'
```

But that gave even more errors. Besides, I wouldn't know what that script loader would be needed. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
As described [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/150) it seems as if NPM installs the node (serverside) version of `pdfmake` instead of the browserside version, both of which have completely different API's. This should be the correct flow for the browserside:

```
npm install pdfmake --save-dev
pdfmake = require 'pdfmake'
pdfmake.createPdf(doc_definition).download('test.pdf')
```

Comment: They have different API for server side i guess...

Answer (score 2):

On server side method createPdf is not supported.

[Server side pdfmake Nodejs - TypeError: pdfmake.createPdf is not a function #1355](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1355)

BUT I tried `var PDF = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake')` and the error is gone.

Also I suggest you to get the `vfs_fonts` too

`var PDF_Fonts=require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts')`

and set the `pdfmake.vfs` like this

`PDF.vfs = PDF_Fonts.pdfMake.vfs;`