# pdf make in a single file

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfmake

Hey i am facing a probleme with exporting pdf make functionality:

```
var pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
var pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

export default pdfMake;
```

import the file with a custom `webpack` alias as `pdfMakeGenerator`:

```
const pdfMake = require('pdfMakeGenerator');
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test");
```

this gives me an error like:

```
pdfMake.createPdf is not a function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494376/pdfmake-pdfmake-createpdf-is-not-a-function

Comment: no it's not, i think it's export problem but i am not sure btw it's for client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was doing it this way:

```
var pdf = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
var pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
pdf.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

export const pdfMake = pdf;
```

then

```
const { pdfMake } = require('pdfMakeGenerator');
```